# accessing ruby standard library documentation locally

Tags: ruby, ri

I'm just getting into Ruby - one of the things I'm having a little trouble letting go of is Intellisense / code completion, so if I don't have that I really need to have the API close to hand at all times. I made the discovery last week of:

```
gem server
```

which starts a server which lets you check out the documentation for all of your installed gems. Is there an equivalent to this which allows you to browse the standard libraries instead of the gems?

Using Linux/Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Are you coding offline a lot? Cause if not, the docs are always there at http://rubydoc.info/stdlib.

Comment: Yeah i code offline a lot while commuting, been using rubydoc when i'm at home but it would still be good to get the docs at the command line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your terminal, you can use `ri` to print specific parts of the documentation. (Note that if you're using RVM to manage your ruby installation(s), you may need to run `rvm docs generate` to avoid getting "Nothing known about...." responses)

For example:

```
> ri Array#drop
```

would output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------- Array#drop
     ary.drop(n)               => array
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Drops first n elements from _ary_, and returns rest elements in an
     array.

        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
        a.drop(3)             # => [4, 5, 0]
```

Comment: I think I'm still missing something dude - this is what I get from your cmd (although I have noticed ri works for other things though):

mikey@mikey-netbook:~$ ri Array#drop
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/json_pure-1.6.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-18 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Nothing known about Array#drop

Comment: it's cool, i think drop might be a 1.9.2 method, the ri command does work for other methods. CHeers!

Comment: Nope, `drop` was around in 1.8.x. But glad to hear it's working otherwise.

Comment: @MikeyHogarth What do you get when you type `ri drop`? What classes are shown?

Comment: Also, if you're using RVM, you may need to run `rvm docs generate` to avoid the "Nothing known about..." errors.

Comment: I am not using `rvm` so how should I get to see the documentation locally?

Comment: What is the option for non-rvm users?

Comment: @Anwar How did you install ruby? I use rbenv now, and `ri` just works without having to do anything.

Comment: I used ubuntu's package installer to install ruby 1.9.1 and rvm to install 2.2.0

Answer (score 5):

Several options:

- [Local, searchable Rails and Ruby docs](http://railsapi.com/) (options to add other docs like haml, rspec, rack, etc., but not quite up-to-date)
- [Create from source](http://gnuu.org/2010/10/13/local-copies-of-documentation/)
- [ri](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_ri_tool.html)
- [... and a million tools to generate snazzy docs from Ruby source](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/documentation_tools), including...
- [doc](https://github.com/toy/doc), which generates local searchable docs of whatever you tell it to; I'm digging it

Comment: The first (railsapi.com) is out of date, `ri` is pretty basic (when you're used to documentation via an IDE or via a web browser - firstly you have to know the class you want the docs on and secondly it doesn't alway work - e.g. `ri String` gives 
Nothing known about String) and the last (doc) didn't work for me with Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: @SnowCrash 1 that's what I said, 2 it is what it is-it's the docs that are in the code, and if you don't generate the docs, there's nothing to show, and 3 could be, but two years ago Ruby 2 didn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

[Devdocs](http://devdocs.io/) does the job

- it works (also) offline
- it is not limited to the ruby doc ;)

Clone the repo from github:

```
git clone git@github.com:Thibaut/devdocs.git
cd devdocs
```

Install dependencies:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

download the docs:

```
thor docs:download --all
```

Run it:

```
rackup
```

It's accessible by default at `http://localhost:9292`