# Generate offline documentation for Ruby source in HTML

Tags: ruby

I'd like to have all the Ruby documentation locally.

I've seen this [accessing ruby standard library documentation locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234181/accessing-ruby-standard-library-documentation-locally)

but none of the answers give a clear, simple solution (as far as I can see).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using *RVM* ?

Comment: you can take a look here [**`Ruby/IRB self help`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049678/ruby-irb-self-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest way I've found.

1. Go to http://www.ruby-doc.org/downloads/ and download your version
2. Unpack (click on it)
3. Open index.html

Comment: You can use also IRB to see the method documentation!